# How many times the letter 'f' is used in French, in order to suppress it?

Tags: linguistique, alphabet, évolution

I would like to know how many times the letter `f` is used in French, because my impression is it's not a very useful letter, and I think it's possible to suppress it.

---

**Combien de fois la lettre `f` a-t-elle été utilisée en français, car peut-être peut-on la supprimer ?**

Je voudrais savoir combien de fois la lettre `f` a-t-elle été utilisée en français, car mon impression est que cette lettre n'est pas très utile, et il me semble qu'il serait possible de la supprimer.

Comment: Well, it's used once in French, so it has to stay // elle est utilisée une fois dans Français, donc elle doit rester.

Comment: @Mat Mais non, on peut très bien parler de la langue de Molière sans cette broutille. Je considère cette question comme intéressante dans la mesure où elle appelle une réponse qui analyse un corpus : non content de compter les mots dans un dictinnaire, il serait bon de compter les utilisations dans les textes.

Comment: Supprimer la lettre « f » ? Mais pourquoi tant de haine ? Et puis, c'est 4 points faciles au Scrabble... ;-)

Comment: (-1) Supprimer une lettre ? Quel est le bénéfice recherché ? Je ne comprends pas l'intérêt de la question... D'autre part, si ton idée (étrange s'il en est) est de "nettoyer" les lettres inusitées, pourquoi choisir le "f" ? Pourquoi pas plutot le "w" ? le "q" ? le "k" ? voire le "y" ?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

On peut assurément pratiquer la langue de Molière sans avoir jamais recours à la lettre qui suit E et précède G dans l'ordre alphabétique. Pour savoir si elle est indispensable, il est surtout vital de repérer quels mots l'utilisent, et de trouver si besoin est des synonymes.

La liste de mots sur laquelle s'appuie mon correcteur orthographique compte 15573 entrées qui contiennent cette lettre sur un total de 140000 moins quelques broutilles, soit 11% (les noms propres et les verbes conjugués sont inclus dans ce décompte). Mais il serait bon de moduler par la rareté de ces mots.

Je ne connais pas de corpus en ligne qui permettrait de dégager des données sur l'utilité d'une lettre, donc j'ai lancé un rapide calcul sur le texte des *Misérables*. Sur 28791 graphies distinctes (en ne séparant pas les majuscules des minuscules, et en comptant donc les noms propres), la 62<sup>e</sup> est la première qui contient la lettre honnie, suivie de la 81<sup>e</sup> et plusieurs autres qui sont des conjugaisons d'un même verbe très courant qui veut dire produire, accomplir, causer, ... D'autres mots courants ont trait à la vie commune, à commencer par les homologues des parents et des hommes. Il y en a au total 2662 (soit un peu plus rare que mon dictionnaire). Si l'on pondère par le nombre d'occurences, 24351 mots contiennent la lettre sur 558371, ce qui montre qu'elle est moins nécessaire que la moyenne.

[On pourrait bannir plus](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_Disparition_%28roman%29) : un trait horizontal haut, un trait horizontal mi-haut mi-bas plus un trait orthogonal irrita d'aucuns quoiqu'un trait horizontal bas l'ornait aussi — « un rond pas clos, conclu par un trait horizontal », approximant un scribouillard qui n'a pas choisi l'initialisation suivant un point.

---

It certainly is possible to write in Molière's tongue without ever using the letter between E and G. To know how dispensible it is, it is mostly important to check which words contain it, and where needed to search synonyms.

The word list used by my spell checker contains 139719 words, amongst which approximately 11% contain the hated letter (3*29*179, to be precise; this includes plurals and conjugated verbs but no proper nouns). However this does not take the words' relative rarity into account.

I don't know any online corpus that permits a query that can measure how many times a letter is used. So I made a quick calculation over *Les Misérables*. It contains 28791 distinct spellings (without distinguishing case). The 62nd word is the most common that contains the letter that shall not be written. Next comes the 81st and several others that are a verb meaning “do” in various tenses and moods. Other common words are related to relationships between humans: children, women. Altogether there are 2662 words containing the letter, which is a lower proportion than my dictionary. I weighed words by the occurrence count, and saw that 12176 minus one contain the letter, the total being twice 279186 minus one. This shows that the letter you wish to ban is noticeably less common than average.

Mayhap your antipathy runs to any symbol that contains two horizontal straight parts (high and middling) plus an orthogonal straight part. Or, [as a known scriptor put it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_Disparition) (though I must stoop to paraphrasing), looking at how it is drawn in most situations, “an oval that is but partial, with a concluding horizontal”. Good luck with that.

Comment: N'avoir utilisé que 23 lettres sur 26 mérite bien +1 :-) En revanche tu n'as épargné aucun de ces symboles numériques…

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez C'est plus dur en anglais, on ne peut pas utiliser 4 ou 5.

Comment: It's now 2 avril, so it's time to resolve this issue :-) I give you the answer bonus, for this ?aboulous e??ort to speak correctly in ?rench and in english ! Thanks. / Comme c'est le 2 avril il est temps de placer ce "problème" en résolu, et je pense que cette réponse est la bonne, etc. Et j'ai donné à toutes les réponses +1, c'est bien le moins :-)

Comment: Ton patronyme serait-il _Perec_, à moins que ce soit _Adair_?

Answer (score 16):

En phait, il y a en Phrance une phoultitude de gens qui soutiennent par leurs ephphorts la cause du replacement de la lettre `f` par l'orthographe `ph`, plus claire. Ce combat pourtant parphaitement justiphié rencontre malheureusement phort peu d'écho dans les médias.

D'aucuns prônent donc un phront commun, ou même une phusion, de ce combat avec çeux qui konçidèrent ke des konçonnes `c`, `s`, `k`, `q` et `z`, çeules çont utiles le `k`, le `z` et le `ç`(ki ne prézente en ephphet pa d'ambigüité). L'avenir nou dira çi çé deux kauze unie pheront çuphphizamment de poid!

Comment: Tu as écris "ephephet", mais peut-être tu voulais dire "ephphet". :D

Comment: Tu m'as fait rire.

Comment: PHORMIDABLE! :-)

Answer (score 7):

Fantastique effort de fantaisie, mais il faut parfois faire face aux faits, fussent-ils fadasses:

La fréquence de `f` en français frôle 1.303% (corpus Frantext)

Référence: http://www.lexique.org/listes/liste_lettres.php

---

The frequency of the letter `f` in French is about 1.303%

Comment: Et je trouve 1,37% de `F` dans *Les Misérables*, donc la proportion a l'air à peu près bonne. Est-ce qu'on peut savoir la fréquence des mots contenant `F`? L'interdire nous prive aussi bien de `fieffé` que d'`interprofessionnelles` et de `fait`,

Answer (score 6):

Cette lettre est très peu utile et ceci est la preuve qu'on peut écrire une réponse complète sans jamais l'utiliser. Une étude récente a par ailleurs démontré que [sa reconnaissance](http://www.kidslearningstation.com/alphabet/letter-f-words.htm) sollicite une trop grande part de notre activité neuronale, et les utilisateurs de ce site ont unanimement décidé qu'elle ne devrait plus être utilisée à partir d'aujourd'hui.

---

Indeed, this letter does not play an important role, and here is evidence that one can write a complete answer without it. Moreover, a recent study has proven that a large part of our neuronal activity is devoted to [its recognition](http://www.kidslearningstation.com/alphabet/letter-f-words.htm), and users of this site have unanimously decided that it shall not be used anymore, starting today.

Comment: Affabulations...

Comment: ...et fatrasies.